# How to avoid errors occur as 'Unable to locate the element'?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, browser-automation

Here I wanted to run this method properly when boolean values are false, but when running this method it always failed the test case saying "no such element: Unable to locate element".How can I handle the boolean = false here?

```
 public void loginToStrata(String email,String psw) throws InterruptedException {
    enterEmail(email);
    enterPassword(psw);
    clickLogin();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    
    boolean emailErrorPresence=driver.findElement(emailError).isDisplayed();
    boolean pswErrorPresence=driver.findElement(pswError).isDisplayed();        
    
    
      if(emailErrorPresence==true){ 
          String emailErrorMessage = driver.findElement(emailError).getText();
          System.out.println(emailErrorMessage);
      }else if (pswErrorPresence==true) {              
          String pswErrorMessage = driver.findElement(pswError).getText(); 
          System.out.println(pswErrorMessage);
      }else if(emailErrorPresence==false && pswErrorPresence==false) {
          boolean sysHeadingPresence=driver.findElement(portalHeading).isDisplayed();
          System.out.println(sysHeadingPresence);
          String heading = driver.findElement(portalHeading).getText(); 
          System.out.println(heading);            
      }      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public void loginToStrata(String email,String psw) throws InterruptedException {
    enterEmail(email);
    enterPassword(psw);
    clickLogin();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    
    List<WebElement> emailErrorPresence=driver.findElements(emailError);
    List<WebElement> pswErrorPresence=driver.findElements(pswError);        
   
    
      if(emailErrorPresence.size()!= 0){ 
          String emailErrorMessage = driver.findElement(emailError).getText();
          System.out.println(emailErrorMessage);
      }else if (pswErrorPresence.size()!=0) {              
          String pswErrorMessage = driver.findElement(pswError).getText(); 
          System.out.println(pswErrorMessage);
      }else if(emailErrorPresence.size()==0 && pswErrorPresence.size()==0) {
          boolean sysHeadingPresence=driver.findElement(portalHeading).isDisplayed();
          System.out.println(sysHeadingPresence);
          String heading = driver.findElement(portalHeading).getText(); 
          System.out.println(heading);            
      }      
}
```

### use findelements instead and check if size() of the returned list is zero if element not exists else != zero

Comment: Thank you so much PDHide,This is working

Comment: can I know what is the reason for using ""List<WebElement>"" here?
@PDHide

Comment: Findelemtns returns a list , we are type casting it meaning we tell that it's a list of only webelements

Answer (score 1):

Write a helper method TryFindElement that doesn't throw an exception but returns false if it isn't found?

Here's my C# example:

```
public bool TryFindElement(By locator)
{
    try
    {
        driver.FindElement(locator);
        return true;
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException)
    {
        return false;
    }
    catch (TargetInvocationException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```